# Equation with multiple variables

Tags: equation-solving

I'm totally new at Mathematica, but I'm stuck with my thesis. I'm trying to solve the following equation with multiple variavles for v, with all variables between 0 and 1, F is larger than f and with p smaller than k.

[image]

equals:

[image]

So I'm trying to solve it by doing:

```
Solve[δ*f+γ*α*(1-β)/(α*(1-β)+(1-α)*(1-β)*(1-v))==(β+(1-β)*v)(c/((1-α)*(1-β)*v*(p-k)^2)(δ*F+γ*α*β/(α*β+(1-α)*(β+(1-β)*v))+(1-c/((1-α)*(1-β)*v*(p-k)^2))γ*α)),v]
```

However, not surprisingly, I do not get any results. I don't really know what I have to do now..
Could someone tell me what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: second equation has delta F instead of delta f (?)

Comment: Yeah, sorry! F stands for large Fee, f for small fee. (F>f)

Comment: Did you mean `γαβ` to represent the product of three variables? The way you have it, it's a single variable with a three letter name. Put space or `*` between them to multiply symbols.

Comment: Yes, these represents the products of the three variables. Thanks!

Comment: I do get a result just takes a long time and it is absurdly long. Could be making mistakes as I am unsure whether `\[Delta]f` is two symbols or one. Same in a couple more places. Can you plug in numerical values before evaluating that would speed things up considerably.

Comment: Yes, I tried to make clear that I meant delta*f, but I'm a total noob, sorry!
I don't know if I can use numerical values, since I'm looking at a microeconomic equilibrium (strategy).

Comment: @B.1993 you should [edit] your question to correct your mistakes first. (`γαβ` to `γ α β`)

Comment: I made a leap of faith and multiplied both sides of your equation to eliminate all denominators, inserted spaces between all characters, and collected together everything multiplied by various powers of v. That gives `Simplify[Solve[v^4*e4 + v^3*e3 + v^2*e2 + v*e1 + e0 == 0, v]]` which is about as simple as the four roots of a quartic are going to get. Then you can substitute the large expressions for e4,e3,e2,e1,e0

Answer (score 1):

An extended comment, not an answer.
Look at

```
\[Delta]*f + \[Gamma]*\[Alpha]*(1 - \[Beta])/(\[Alpha]*(1 - \[Beta]) \
+ (1 - \[Alpha])*(1 - \[Beta])*(1 - v)) - (\[Beta] + (1 - \[Beta])*
       v) (c/((1 - \[Alpha])*(1 - \[Beta])*v*(p - k)^2) (\[Delta]*
         F + \[Gamma]*\[Alpha]*\[Beta]/(\[Alpha]*\[Beta] + (1 - \
\[Alpha])*(\[Beta] + (1 - \[Beta])*v)) + (1 - 
           c/((1 - \[Alpha])*(1 - \[Beta])*
              v*(p - k)^2)) \[Gamma]*\[Alpha])) // 
  Together // Numerator
```

obtained by subtracting the right side from the left and taking the numerator of the resulting rational function. I don't show the huge result. `Solve` is attempting to find the zeros of this monstrosity. The roots will be even more monstrous. What are you trying to accomplish here? A symbolic result exists, but will be incomprehensible and slow to evaluate. Substituting numbers for symbolic parameters and using `NSolve` or `FindRoot` to get numeric answers may be more practical.

Comment: I was trying to find one or multiple values of v, for which a game theoretical equilibrium could exist. So therefore I needed to have a value of v for which both the left hand side and the right hand side of the equation are equal (These functions represent micro-economic utility functions for a certain strategy). But looking at these outcomes, I don't think this will be doable right now (for me).
Thanks for the help anyways!